# Stop SQL*Plus Complaining About Whitespace

Tags: oracle, whitespace, sqlplus, code-structure

In SQL*Plus, if you execute the following using `@`:

```
create table someTable (
  someID            number,

  somethingElse     varchar2(50),
  somethingRelated  number
);
```

...it will complain with something like:

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning...
...
...
```

This is because it doesn't like the empty line between the `someID` and `somethingElse` column definitions. However, leaving that line makes the source code look a *lot* more readable.

Is there some flag/option to stop it doing this? I don't want to get rid of all the whitespace in my code. (If not, I'll just use SQL Developer, which has no problem with the spacing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have Google'd this first :P

```
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
```

...fixes the problem.

See http://nerdydeeds.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/sp2-0734-oracle-sqlplus/